# How to call function without leaving insert mode?

Tags: vim

I am trying to create a plugin for vim like ctrlp and I need some help. First of all I want to place input field at the top of the screen so

1. Is there a function similar to `input()` but which can place input field at the top?

Friendly speaking, I have already started to realize my own input field and there is an issue while editing text. I have found a `backspace` option very useful to prevent deleting prompt text ("Files> "). I just put this text to the buffer and then start insert mode. To my regret I cannot use this option because I have complex logic to control buffer and I always need exit insert mode to call functions. Instead of `backspace` I need remap `<BS>` to something like this `<C-o>:call backspace()<CR>`

```
function backspace()
    " checks if deletion is possible
    x
endfunction
```

This works but there is a cursor flashing which disturbs me. Insert mode makes buffer modified and there is a mark * in `tabline`. It can be hidden  `call setbufvar(bufnr('%'), '&mod', 0)` but it works quite slow and the symbol appears from time to time. I use `TextChangedI` event for this.

2. Is there an option to disable monitoring buffer change?

The most important question is how can I get more freedom in insert mode? Is there a way to calling function without leaving this mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Is there a function similar to `input()` but which can place input field at the top?

   No. The command-line is at the bottom and there's nothing you can do about it.
2. Is there an option to disable monitoring buffer change?

   Yes. See the last paragraph of `:help 'modified'`.

Comment: Thank you for `buftype`. As simple as possible. Any thoughts how to prevent cursor flashing?

Comment: I don't get what you mean by "cursor flashing".

Comment: English is not my native language, maybe I should have said "cursor blink". After an hour of debugging I've found the reason. When I call a function I go to ex mode which hides the cursor.